# react router v6 redirect with params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code:

```
<Route
   path=":teamId"
   element={<Navigate to=":teamId/league" replace />}
/>

<Route path=":teamId/*" element={<TeamsPage />} />
```

When a user comes to `http:localhost:3000/liverpool` I want them to be redirected to `http:localhost:3000/liverpool/league` but I see the following in the url

> http:localhost:3000/:teamId/league

Can anyone help? I am already tearing my hair out with this upgrade from v5 -> v6. I'm nearly there but it certainly hasn't been easy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should redirect to `:teamId/league`:

```js
<Route
   path=":teamId"
   element={<Navigate to="league" />}
/>
```

The forward slash in the `to` attribute before `league` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are redirecting to the path string literal `":teamId/league"` instead of using a relative path or another template literal. This will, OFC, result in redirecting to `"http:localhost:3000/:teamId/league"`.

## Solution

A solution would be to use a layout route on path `"/:teamId"` and use the index route to redirect to the nested `"league"` route rendering the `TeamsPage` component.

```
<Route path=":teamId">
  <Route index element={<Navigate to="league" replace />} />
  <Route path="league" element={<TeamsPage />} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Route path=':teamId/*' element={<TeamsPage />} />
<Route path=':teamId' element={<Navigate to='league' />} />
```